# Not at all able to understand the concept of storing pixel data in an array

Tags: c, pointers, rgb

(Assignment that has already been submitted) What I turned in did not even compile. This is not for points, its purely for understanding (peek the due date) I was able to complete the rest of the assignment however since I couldnt figure out how to save pixel data relative to height/ width.Ive literally spent the last 5 hours trying to understand this but it just isnt clicking.

How would I save the individual pixel rgb values. When the image is being read in, how can I tell the program @ height 1, width 1 , read that green = 200, blue = ..., red = ....?  Also if anyone knows what maxVal is referring to that would be helpful

```
typdef struct
{
        unsigned char green;
        unsigned char blue;
        unsigned char red;
}pixelD;

typedef struct
{       
        pixelD * pixel;
} Color;



imageData


Image * ReadImage(char *filename)
{
//* items were added by instructor. I dont see how the magicNum array 
     would be useful here 
/* These lines are useful:
 * char magicNum[128];    
 * int width, height, maxval;    
   int imgSize = (width * height * sizeof(pixel)); 
 * fscanf(f_in,  "%s\n%d %d\n%d\n", magicNum, &width, &height, &maxval);
   pixel = malloc(imgSize); 
   fread()????? this is supposedly the key?
```

Assignment: You will    begin   manipulation    of  images
1) Write    a   struct  to  store   an  image.

==  2.1 Image   struct  ==
Your    Image   struct  will    need    a   width,  a   height, and a   buffer  to  store   image   data.       As
we  discussed   in  class,  image   data    is  a   2D  array   of  pixel   data.       A   pixel   contains    3   unsigned    chars:  one for red,    one for green,  and one for blue. There are multiple    ways
to  store   this    data,   and they    are all correct

Comment: Image data can be stored in hundreds of different ways: these are called *file formats", with names like PNG, GIF, JPEG, TIFF, RAW, PNM, etc.

Comment: we are storing a pnm

Comment: Good--PNMs are uncompressed and simple. Just getchar() the first two bytes of the file to verify the format (they'll be "P1, P2...etc"), and then follow the rules for that format. 1-3 are text, so can read with fgets(). 4-6 are binary, so you should use fread().

Answer (score 0):

The steps you need to perform are:

1. Read the height and Width
2. Calculate the size of the buffer in which to save the data
3. Allocate the space for the buffer
4. Read the data and put it in the buffer.

The comments in ReadImage get you most of the way to solving this.  Just put them in order and define the variable names.